# Limit for unbounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $\lim a_n  = +\infty$. Let $N^* \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it correct to write $\lim a_n - a_{N^*} = \lim a_n$.

$(a_n \in \mathbb{R})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by the way

I am in the middle of proving Stolz–Cesàro theorem

Starting from $\lim \frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_{n}} = L$, I have successfully shown that $\lim \frac{a_n - a_{N^*}}{b_n - b_{N^*}} = L$ (111)

where $\lim b_n = +\infty$ and $b_n \neq 0$ for all n, $b_n$ is strictly increasing and $\lim b_n - b_{N^*} \neq 0$.

(111) $\implies \frac{\lim a_n - a_{N^*}}{\lim b_n - b_{N^*}} = L$

Goal is to show $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L$.

Comment: If $\lim a_n = + \infty$ then you can say that $\lim (a_n - x) = +\infty$ for any fixed constant $x$; in particular, with $x = a_N$. However, you should be careful when dealing with $\frac{+ \infty}{+ \infty}$ limits, not sure if you want to apply it directly...

Comment: I mean, you expression $\frac{\lim a_n - a_N}{\lim b_n - b_N} = L$ is wrong, since both are infinite.

Comment: But the quotient rule for limits says: $\lim \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{\lim f(n)}{\lim g(n)}$ if $\lim g(n) \neq 0$. See https://www.math24.net/properties-limits/

Comment: Although it is not written explicitly on that link, they assume that the limits are finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you should be careful when writing expressions like $\frac{+ \infty}{+ \infty}$. E.g., your equation
$$
\frac{\lim a_n}{\lim b_n} = L
$$
does not make sense.

However, you can adapt the expressions to get finite limits. Notice that
$$
\frac{a_n - a_N}{b_n - b_N}
= \frac{\frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{a_N}{b_n}}{1 - \frac{b_N}{b_n}}.
$$
Thus, you can write
\begin{align*}
\lim_n \left(\frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{a_N}{b_n}\right)
&= \lim_n \left[
  \frac{a_n - a_N}{b_n - b_N} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{b_N}{b_n}\right)
  \right] \\
&= \lim_n \frac{a_n - a_N}{b_n - b_N} \cdot \lim \left(1 - \frac{b_N}{b_n}\right) \\
&= L \cdot 1 \\
&= L.
\end{align*}
Here we could separate the product into two limits because in this case both limits **are finite.** Moreover, notice that
$$
\lim_n \frac{a_n}{b_n}
= \lim_n \left(\frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{a_N}{b_n} + \frac{a_N}{b_n} \right)
= \lim_n \left(\frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{a_N}{b_n} \right) + \lim_n \frac{a_N}{b_n}
= L + 0 = L.
$$
Once again, a crucial point here is that when we separate the limit of the sum into the sum of the limits, both limits are known to be finite.